# Remove substring from a string knowing first and last characters in Swift

Tags: swift, string

Having a string like this:

```
let str = "In 1273, however, they lost their son in an accident;[2] the young Theobald was dropped by his nurse over the castle battlements.[3]"
```

I'm looking for a solution of removing all appearances of square brackets and anything that between it.

I was trying using a String's method: `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`, but it requires the exact substring it needs to be removed, so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try using regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
let updated = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\[[^\\]]+\\]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

The regular expression (without the required escapes needed in a Swift string is:

```
\[[^\]+]\]
```

The `\[` and `\]` look for the characters `[` and `]`. They have a backslash to remove the normal special meaning of those characters in a regular expression.

The `[^]]` means to match any character except the `]` character. The `+` means match 1 or more.

Comment: Whoa, that's a lot of backslashes :) Great explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a while loop to get the lowerBound of the range of the first string and the upperBound of the range of the second string and create a range from that. Next just remove the subrange of your string and set the new startIndex for the search.

```
var str = "In 1273, however, they lost their son in an accident;[2] the young Theobald was dropped by his nurse over the castle battlements.[3]"

var start = str.startIndex

while let from = str.range(of: "[", range: start..<str.endIndex)?.lowerBound,
    let to = str.range(of: "]", range: from..<str.endIndex)?.upperBound,
    from != to {
        str.removeSubrange(from..<to)
        start = from
}

print(str)   // "In 1273, however, they lost their son in an accident; the young Theobald was dropped by his nurse over the castle battlements."
```